# Ajax calling memcache functions always querying Db

Tags: php, ajax, memcached

I'm experiencing a strange problem. I'm caching the output of a query using memcache functions in a file named count.php. This file is called by an ajax every second when a user is viewing a particular page. The output is cached for 5 seconds, so within this time if there will be 5 hits to this file  i expect the cached result to be returned 3-4 times atleast. However this is not happening, instead everytime a query is going to db as evidenced from a echo statement,  but if the file is called from the browser directly by typing the url (like http://example.com/help/count.php) repeatedly many times within 5 seconds data is returned from cache (again evidenced from the echo statement). Below is the relevant code of count.php

```
mysql_connect(c_dbhost, c_dbuname, c_dbpsw) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(c_dbname) or die("Coud Not Find Database");

$product_id=$_POST['product_id'];

echo func_total_bids_count($product_id);


function func_total_bids_count($product_id)
{
    $qry="select count(*) as bid_count from tbl_userbid where userbid_auction_id=".$product_id;
    $row_count=func_row_count_only($qry);
    return $row_count["bid_count"];
}

function func_row_count_only($qry)
{
    if($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]!="localhost")
    {
        $o_cache = new Memcache;
        $o_cache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect to memcache");
        //$key="total_bids" . md5($product_id);
        $key = "KEY" . md5($qry);
        $result = $o_cache->get($key);
        if (!$result) 
        {
            $qry_result = mysql_query($qry);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)) 
            {
                $row_count = $row;
                $result = $row;
                $o_cache->set($key, $result, 0, 5);
            }
            echo "From DB <br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "From Cache <br/>";
        }
            $o_cache->close();
        return $row_count;
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to why when an ajax calls this file, DB is hit every second, but when the URL is typed in the browser cached data is returned. To try the URL method i just replaced $product_id with a valid number (Eg: $product_id=426 in my case). I'm not understanding whats wrong here as i expect data to be returned from cache within 5 seconds after the 1st hit. I want the data to be returned from cache. Can some one please help me understand whats happening ?

Comment: can you change `if (!$result) ` to `if( false === $result )`. That way, if the result is 0 it will also use the cache. Now, if the count is 0 it wont use the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the address bar, you're doing a GET, but your code is looking for $_POST['...'], so you will end up with an invalid query. So for a start, the results using the address bar won't be what you're expecting. Is your Ajax call actually doing a POST?

Please also note that you've got a SQL injection vulnerability there. Make sure $product_id is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code, first of all you always connect to the database and select a table, even if you don't need it. Second, you should check $result with **!empty($result)** which is more reliable as just **!$result**, because it's also covers empty objects.

As above noted, if the 'product_id' is not in the $_POST array, you could use $_REQUEST to also cover $_GET (but you shouldn't, if you are certain it's coming via $_POST).